# SQL Server Temp table to update Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code, when I run it I get the following:

```
 DECLARE @Consumption float = 2211,
            @BillingMonth datetime = '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000',
            @SiteName varchar(100) = 'Aldr',
            @Type int = 1


    SELECT Consumption, MeterID, SiteID
    FROM  tblMEP_Sites

    JOIN tblMEP_Meters
    ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID

    JOIN tblMEP_Monthlydata
    ON tblMEP_MonthlyData.MeterID = tblMEP_Meters.ID

    WHERE ProjectID = 40
    AND tblMEP_Sites.Name LIKE @SiteName

    AND Type = @Type
    AND BillingMonth = @BillingMonth
```

Result:

```
Consumption MeterID SiteID
25900   13274   1622
```

I want to update the consumption field using the the update Statement:

```
Update tblMEP_Monthlydata
SET Consumption= @Consumption
```

And Also get the MeterID and the SiteID so the result will be as the following:

```
Consumption MeterID SiteID
2211        13274   1622
```

Is tempTables the solution for this problem? If yes, how would I convert the above code to Temp tables?

Comment: Currently we have no idea how your `ConsumptionTable` releates to any of the other tables

Comment: Sorry! It is tblMEP_Monthlydata

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @Consumption float = 2211,
            @BillingMonth datetime = '2012-11-01 00:00:00.000',
            @SiteName varchar(100) = 'Aldr',
            @Type int = 1

    UPDATE tblMEP_Monthlydata 
    set 
    Consumption = @Consumption


    FROM  tblMEP_Sites

    JOIN tblMEP_Meters
    ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID

    JOIN tblMEP_Monthlydata
    ON tblMEP_MonthlyData.MeterID = tblMEP_Meters.ID

    WHERE ProjectID = 40
    AND tblMEP_Sites.Name LIKE @SiteName

    AND Type = @Type
    AND BillingMonth = @BillingMonth
```

Comment: I don't think that updating all rows on that table is what op wants.

Comment: Not really, you just added `UPDATE` to the code already provided. I think that if you wanted to point him/her on the right direction without waiting for clarification, you could've at least *assume* a column on `ConsumptionTable` to use on a `JOIN` there

Comment: Really he is asking about using a temp table, this points out no need for a temp table.  You feel this answer has no value.

Comment: I never said the answer had no value. If I had thought that, I would've downvoted it, which I didn't

Answer (score 0):

You want to first do an `UPDATE` and then a `SELECT` of your data.

```
UPDATE MD
SET Consumption = @Consumption
FROM  tblMEP_Sites S
INNER JOIN tblMEP_Meters M
    ON M.SiteID = S.ID
INNER JOIN tblMEP_Monthlydata MD
    ON MD.MeterID = M.ID
WHERE ProjectID = 40                -- use the table alias as a prefix 
AND S.Name LIKE @SiteName           -- changed the LIKE with "=" because 
                                    -- they are doing the same
AND Type = @Type                    -- use the table alias as a prefix
AND BillingMonth = @BillingMonth    -- use the table alias as a prefix


SELECT Consumption, MeterID, SiteID
FROM  tblMEP_Sites S
INNER JOIN tblMEP_Meters M
    ON M.SiteID = S.ID
INNER JOIN tblMEP_Monthlydata MD
    ON MD.MeterID = M.ID
WHERE ProjectID = 40                
AND S.Name LIKE @SiteName           
AND Type = @Type                    
AND BillingMonth = @BillingMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
    Consumption FLOAT,
    MeterID INT,
    SiteI INT
);

UPDATE  tblMEP_Monthlydata
SET     Consumption = @Consumption 
OUTPUT  inserted.Consumption, inserted.MeterID, inserted.SiteID INTO @Results
/*
-- Or, if this combination of values (ProjectID=40,Name,Type,BillingMonth) is unique (maybe you have an [unique] index view ?)
-- then you could use this syntax
SET     Consumption = @Consumption, 
        @MeterID = MeterID,
        @SiteID = SiteID
*/      
FROM    tblMEP_Sites
JOIN    tblMEP_Meters ON tblMEP_Meters.SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID
JOIN    tblMEP_Monthlydata ON tblMEP_MonthlyData.MeterID = tblMEP_Meters.ID
WHERE   ProjectID = 40
AND     tblMEP_Sites.Name = @SiteName
AND     Type = @Type
AND     BillingMonth = @BillingMonth

SELECT * FROM @Results;
```